# Pandas: Shift down values by one row within a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe, and I want to create a new column whose values are that of another column, shifted down by one row. The last row should show NaN.

The catch is that I want to do this by group, with the last row of each group showing NaN. NOT have the last row of a group "steal" a value from a group that happens to be adjacent in the dataframe.

My attempted implementation is quite shamefully broken, so I'm clearly misunderstanding something fundamental.

```
df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x:x.values[1:])
```

Comment: Does this work: `df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x:x.shift())`?

Comment: Whenever there's something slightly tricky I want to do in Pandas, there's already a function written that does just that. Except I never know it exists or how to find it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shift works on the output of the groupby clause:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(1,3, (10,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  2  1  2  1  1
1  2  1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2  1  2
3  1  2  1  1  2
4  2  2  1  1  2
5  2  2  2  2  1
6  2  2  1  1  1
7  2  2  2  1  1
8  2  2  2  2  1
9  2  2  2  2  1


for k, v in df.groupby('a'):
    print k
    print 'normal'
    print v
    print 'shifted'
    print v.shift(1)

1
normal
   a  b  c  d  e
2  1  2  2  1  2
3  1  2  1  1  2
shifted
    a   b   c   d   e
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   1   2   2   1   2
2
normal
   a  b  c  d  e
0  2  1  2  1  1
1  2  1  1  1  1
4  2  2  1  1  2
5  2  2  2  2  1
6  2  2  1  1  1
7  2  2  2  1  1
8  2  2  2  2  1
9  2  2  2  2  1
shifted
    a   b   c   d   e
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2   1   2   1   1
4   2   1   1   1   1
5   2   2   1   1   2
6   2   2   2   2   1
7   2   2   1   1   1
8   2   2   2   1   1
9   2   2   2   2   1
```

Comment: default param for shift is 1 so not necessary to set `shift(1)` although it is clearer code by specifiying it

Answer (score 79):

Newer versions of pandas can now perform a `shift` on a group:

```
df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].shift(1)
```

Note that when shifting *down*, it's the *first* row that has NaN.

Comment: I am getting all the rows NaN

Comment: @GammaCat I have reverted your revision. You are entitled to post your own answer. Do **not** change the code in an existing answer; edits are for formatting and typographical errors, not code changes.

Comment: @AshokRayal That could due to each groupby has only one row, when shift, it becomes NaN.

Comment: Thanks @william007. I got it after some time.

Answer (score 18):

@EdChum's comment is a better answer to this question, so I'm posting it here for posterity:

`df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x:x.shift())`

or similarly

`df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform('shift')`.

The former notation is more flexible, of course (e.g. if you want to shift by 2).

Comment: does this create a new column?

Comment: @Boris: yes, that's what the assignment on the left-hand side is doing.

Comment: `df['B_shifted'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform('shift', 2)` is also working.