# Column with difference between two timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas dataframe` which looks like this :

```
userID     timestamp                 other_data
1          2017-06-19 17:14:00.000   foo
1          2017-06-19 19:16:00.000   bar
1          2017-06-19 23:26:00.000   ter
1          2017-06-20 01:16:00.000   lol
2          2017-06-20 12:00:00.000   ter
2          2017-06-20 13:15:00.000   foo
2          2017-06-20 17:15:00.000   bar
```

I'd like to add two columns, `time_since_previous_point` and `time_until_next_point`, but only between points of each user of course. I don't really care about the unit/format for now (as long as I can switch easily between them) :

```
userID     timestamp                 time_since_previous   time_until_next  other data
1          2017-06-19 17:14:00.000                         02:02:00.000     foo
1          2017-06-19 19:16:00.000   02:02:00.000          04:10:00.000     bar
1          2017-06-19 23:26:00.000   04:10:00.000          01:50:00.000     ter
1          2017-06-20 01:16:00.000   01:50:00.000                           lol
2          2017-06-20 12:00:00.000                         01:15:00.000     ter
2          2017-06-20 13:15:00.000   01:15:00.000          04:00:00.000     foo
2          2017-06-20 17:15:00.000   04:00:00.000                           bar
```

How can I do that ? (The cells that are empty can be either `empty`, `NaN`, `None`, depending on what seems best to you, knowing that next, I will be doing descriptive statistics on `time_since_previous` and `time_until_next`)

Please note that here, I denoted the `userID` as being just one column, but in reality, my unique way to identify user is a combination of columns (`country` + `userID`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is a pandas [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function  and this answer:  [Pandas: Shift down values by one row within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280345/pandas-shift-down-values-by-one-row-within-a-group).

Combining both together you can do it like this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
csv = """userID,timestamp,other_data
1,2017-06-19 17:14:00.000,foo
1,2017-06-19 19:16:00.000,bar
1,2017-06-19 23:26:00.000,ter
1,2017-06-20 01:16:00.000,lol
2,2017-06-20 12:00:00.000,ter
2,2017-06-20 13:15:00.000,foo
2,2017-06-20 17:15:00.000,bar
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
```

gives:

```
   userID                timestamp other_data
0       1  2017-06-19 17:14:00.000        foo
1       1  2017-06-19 19:16:00.000        bar
2       1  2017-06-19 23:26:00.000        ter
3       1  2017-06-20 01:16:00.000        lol
4       2  2017-06-20 12:00:00.000        ter
5       2  2017-06-20 13:15:00.000        foo
6       2  2017-06-20 17:15:00.000        bar
```

First, you need to convert `timestamp` to `datetime` column:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

And then combine `groupby` and `shift` methods:

```
df['time_since_previous'] = df['timestamp'] - df.groupby('userID')['timestamp'].shift(1)
df['time_until_next'] = df.groupby('userID')['timestamp'].shift(-1) - df['timestamp']
```

Which, ultimately, give you what you want:

```
userID           timestamp other_data  time_since_previous  time_until_next
0       1 2017-06-19 17:14:00        foo                  NaT         02:02:00
1       1 2017-06-19 19:16:00        bar             02:02:00         04:10:00
2       1 2017-06-19 23:26:00        ter             04:10:00         01:50:00
3       1 2017-06-20 01:16:00        lol             01:50:00              NaT
4       2 2017-06-20 12:00:00        ter                  NaT         01:15:00
5       2 2017-06-20 13:15:00        foo             01:15:00         04:00:00
6       2 2017-06-20 17:15:00        bar             04:00:00              NaT
```

The only thing left for you is to deal with `NaT`s.