# Lagging by date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lag, shift

I have a pandas dataframe. LAG_VAL presented below is how my result should look like.

```
A     DT           VAL  LAG_VAL
1     2017-01-10    1     nan
1     2018-01-10    2      1
2     2017-01-10    1     nan
2     2018-01-10    2      1
2     2019-01-10    3      2
```

I run the code below, but it is giving me all nan values.

```
df['LAG_VAL'] = df.groupby(['A','DT'])['VAL'].shift(1)
```

I have made sure that the data type of DT is datetime64[ns]. I have also made sure that the dataframe is sorted before shifting.

```
df.sort(['A,'DT], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Shift down values by one row within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280345/pandas-shift-down-values-by-one-row-within-a-group)

Answer (score 2):

You only want to groupby 'A':

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['A'])['VAL'].shift(1)
Out[11]:
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    2.0
Name: VAL, dtype: float64
```

---

It might be what you want is to shift by offset rather than by position:

```
In [21]: df1 = df.set_index("DT")

In [22]: df1.groupby(['A'])['VAL'].shift(freq=pd.offsets.YearBegin(1))
Out[22]:
A  DT
1  2018-01-01    1
   2019-01-01    2
2  2018-01-01    1
   2019-01-01    2
   2020-01-01    3
Name: VAL, dtype: int64
```