# Python Pandas - New column based on previous value in another column by group

Tags: python, pandas

This is the data

```
User    Date    Status
1   1/1/2018    A
1   1/2/2018    B
1   1/3/2018    C
2   1/4/2018    D
2   1/5/2018    E
3   1/6/2018    F
3   1/7/2018    G
3   1/8/2018    H
```

I'm trying to get to this

```
User    Date    Status  Previous
1   1/1/2018    A       NaN
1   1/2/2018    B       A
1   1/3/2018    C       B
2   1/4/2018    D       NaN
2   1/5/2018    E       D
3   1/6/2018    F       NaN
3   1/7/2018    G       F
3   1/8/2018    H       G
```

I've tried to use the shift method but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
df.sort_values(by=['user', 'date'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
df.set_index(['user', 'date'], inplace=True)
df['Previous'] = np.nan
for idx in df.index.levels[0]:
    df.Previous[idx] = df.Status[idx].shift()
```

Comment: Why do you have `NaN`s in place of `C` and `E` in the shifted column you're trying to get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603767/9609447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track by trying to use `shift`, but it can be done much more quickly using `groupby` rather than iterating (generally, iterating through a dataframe is clunky and there are better methods built into `pandas`):

```
df['Previous'] = df.groupby('User')['Status'].shift()

>>> df
   User      Date Status Previous
0     1  1/1/2018      A      NaN
1     1  1/2/2018      B        A
2     1  1/3/2018      C        B
3     2  1/4/2018      D      NaN
4     2  1/5/2018      E        D
5     3  1/6/2018      F      NaN
6     3  1/7/2018      G        F
7     3  1/8/2018      H        G
```