# fill_value in the pandas shift doesn't work with groupby

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I need to shift column in pandas dataframe, for every name and fill resulting NA's with predefined value. Below is code snippet compiled with python 2.7

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['Petro', 'Petro', 'Petro', 'Petro', 'Petro', 'Mykola', 'Mykola', 'Mykola', 'Mykola', 'Mykola', 'Mykyta', 'Mykyta', 'Mykyta', 'Mykyta', 'Mykyta'],
     'Month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'Value': [25, 2.5, 24.6, 28, 26.4, 35, 24, 35, 22, 27, 30, 30, 34, 30, 23]
     }
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
data['ValueLag'] = data.groupby('Name').Value.shift(-1, fill_value = 20)

print data
```

After running code above I get the following output

```
    Month    Name  Value  ValueLag
0       1   Petro   25.0       2.5
1       2   Petro    2.5      24.6
2       3   Petro   24.6      28.0
3       4   Petro   28.0      26.4
4       5   Petro   26.4       NaN
5       1  Mykola   35.0      24.0
6       2  Mykola   24.0      35.0
7       3  Mykola   35.0      22.0
8       4  Mykola   22.0      27.0
9       5  Mykola   27.0       NaN
10      1  Mykyta   30.0      30.0
11      2  Mykyta   30.0      34.0
12      3  Mykyta   34.0      30.0
13      4  Mykyta   30.0      23.0
14      5  Mykyta   23.0       NaN
```

Looks like fill_value did not work here. While I need NaN to be filled with some number let's say 4.

Or if to tell all the story I need that last value to be extended like this

```
   Month    Name  Value  ValueLag
0       1   Petro   25.0       2.5
1       2   Petro    2.5      24.6
2       3   Petro   24.6      28.0
3       4   Petro   28.0      26.4
4       5   Petro   26.4       26.4
5       1  Mykola   35.0      24.0
6       2  Mykola   24.0      35.0
7       3  Mykola   35.0      22.0
8       4  Mykola   22.0      27.0
9       5  Mykola   27.0       27.0
10      1  Mykyta   30.0      30.0
11      2  Mykyta   30.0      34.0
12      3  Mykyta   34.0      30.0
13      4  Mykyta   30.0      23.0
14      5  Mykyta   23.0       23.0
```

Is there a way to fill with last value forward or first value backward if shifting positive number of periods?

Comment: add `.ffill()` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the fill value is by group rather than a single value. Try the following,

```
data['ValueLag'] = data.groupby('Name').Value.shift(-1).ffill()
```

Comment: The example provided looks like `ffill` rather than `fillna(20)`

Comment: @ jezrael together with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280345/pandas-shift-down-values-by-one-row-within-a-group