# Use the shift() function considering as criterion the value of another column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column that gets the previous Target value. For this, I need to take care of the Id_Sensor. In the first iteration of each new Id_Sensor, Reccurent_Target must be 'NaN'.

I created this line, but it is not correct because it does not check if there was a change in Id_Sensor

```
    df['Reccurent_Target'] = df['Target'].shift(1)
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
     import pandas as pd

     df = pd.DataFrame({'Id_Sensor': [108, 108, 108, 880, 880, 880, 880],
                       'Target':  [5, 5, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20]})

      print(df)
```

I would like the output to be as below:

```
       Id_Sensor  Target        Reccurent_Target
         108       5              NaN
         108       5                5
         108       5                5
         880      20              NaN
         880      20               20
         880      10               20
         880      20               10
```

However, with the line that I implemented the output was:

```
      Id_Sensor  Target        Reccurent_Target
         108       5              NaN
         108       5                5
         108       5                5
         880      20                5
         880      20               20
         880      10               20
         880      20               10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Shift down values by one row within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280345/pandas-shift-down-values-by-one-row-within-a-group)

Answer (score 1):

You need `groupby`

```
df['Reccurent_Target'] = df.groupby('Id_Sensor').Target.shift()


Out[65]:
   Id_Sensor  Target  Reccurent_Target
0        108       5               NaN
1        108       5               5.0
2        108       5               5.0
3        880      20               NaN
4        880      20              20.0
5        880      10              20.0
6        880      20              10.0
```