# Pulling previous date Data from DataFrame based on a condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I'm brand new to Python and have a question regarding pulling data from a df based on the previous date for a given team. This is an example of what I'm looking at;

```
import Pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Duke', 'Duke', 'Duke', 'Kentucky', 'Kentucky'], 
               'Date':['1-1-20', '1-3-20', '1-7-20', '1-8-20', '1-11-20'],
               'Points Scored':['85', '90', '75', '73', '82']})
df

   Team       Date       Points Scored
0   Duke     1-1-20          85
1   Duke     1-3-20          90
2   Duke     1-7-20          75
3   Kentucky 1-8-20          73
4   Kentucky 1-11-20         82
```

The desired output would pull the points scored for each team from the previous date. If for example it's the first game of the year it'd output a 0. I've tried to use the merge function/shifting dates but it seems so messy. Was wondering if anyone has an easier way to get the following output and would apply to a larger data set with all ~353 teams;

```
 Team       Date      Points Scored  Previous Game Points Scored
 0  Duke     1-1-20          85              0
 1  Duke     1-3-20          90              85
 2  Duke     1-7-20          75              90
 3  Kentucky 1-8-20          73              0
 4  Kentucky 1-11-20         82              73
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Shift down values by one row within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280345/pandas-shift-down-values-by-one-row-within-a-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html),

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Duke', 'Duke', 'Duke', 'Kentucky', 'Kentucky'],
               'Date':['1-1-20', '1-3-20', '1-7-20', '1-8-20', '1-11-20'],
               'Points Scored':['85', '90', '75', '73', '82']})

df['Previous Game Points Scored'] = (df
    .groupby('Team')['Points Scored']
    .transform('shift')
    .fillna(0))

print(df)
       Team     Date Points Scored Previous Game Points Scored
0      Duke   1-1-20            85                           0
1      Duke   1-3-20            90                          85
2      Duke   1-7-20            75                          90
3  Kentucky   1-8-20            73                           0
4  Kentucky  1-11-20            82                          73
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad! :) If my answer was helpful, don't forget [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.

Comment: Sorry just getting back to this, I accepted your answer. Thanks again!