# Python - Pulling previous date and other data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to be able to take a date in mm/dd/yyyy format and pull the next most recent date and a corresponding other value and place both of them in new columns in the row with the next most recent date, while holding 2 other variables constant.  The new columns would be left blank if there nothing matched the criteria.

I found this:

[Pulling previous date Data from DataFrame based on a condition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794995/pulling-previous-date-data-from-dataframe-based-on-a-condition-in-python)

which gets me close, but not quite what I need.

So, in the example below, if Team Name and Game Type are the same and there are two or more dates in that set, then the most recent date will pull the data from the next most recent date and so on.

Original:

```
| Team Name  |   Game Type    |    Score    |     Date     |
| Tigers     |   Away         |      50     |    1/21/21   |
| Tigers     |   Home         |      47     |    2/20/21   |
| Tigers     |   Away         |      29     |    1/30/21   |
| Lions      |   Home         |      52     |    2/1/21    |
```

Desired Output:
Original:

```
| Team Name  |   Game Type    |    Score    |     Date     |    Previous Score   |   Previous Date  |
| Tigers     |   Away         |      50     |    1/21/21   |                     |                  |
| Tigers     |   Home         |      47     |    2/20/21   |                     |                  |
| Tigers     |   Away         |      29     |    1/30/21   |         50          |     1/21/21      |
| Lions      |   Home         |      52     |    2/1/21    |                     |                  |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can groupby and shift after sorting by date and assign to two different columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
'''
TeamName,GameType,Score,Date
Tigers,Away,50,1/21/21
Tigers,Home,47,2/20/21
Tigers,Away,29,1/30/21
Lions,Home,52,2/1/21
'''),sep=',')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df[['PreviousScore','PreviousDate']] = df.groupby(['TeamName','GameType']).shift(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    TeamName    GameType    Score   Date    PreviousScore   PreviousDate
0   Tigers      Away        50      1/21/21 NaN             NaN
2   Tigers      Away        29      1/30/21 50.0            1/21/21
3   Lions       Home        52      2/1/21  NaN             NaN
1   Tigers      Home        47      2/20/21 NaN             NaN
```